# CKEditor placeholder icon not showing in toolbar

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, text-editor

The placeholder icon is supposed to automatically display in the toolbar but it doesn't.  Everything else is working just fine.  It's a very simple implementation.  Why is it missing??

JAVASCRIPT CONFIG FILE

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.height = 500;
    config.toolbar = 'MyToolbar';
    config.extraPlugins = "placeholder";
    config.extraPlugins = "widget";
};
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="editor1" cols="80" name="editor1" rows="10">Hello world</textarea>
<script>
CKEDITOR.replace("editor1", {});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is not automatically added. Try This:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
    extraPlugins: 'placeholder',
    toolbar: [ [ 'Source', 'Bold' ], ['CreatePlaceholder'] ]
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After building and downloading CKeditor I also found that some icons were not showing but the functionality was still working.
I tried to edit using the ckeditor configuration editor but it didn't even always work for me after a download
I worked around this by directly editing ckeditor/config.js file to remove the references to the icons in icons.png and icons_hidpi.png files
for example I removed these

```
emojione,2856,auto,
emojione,2688,auto,
```

and

```
symbol,9984,auto,
symbol,10608,auto,
```

then I added the actual icons I wanted, by creating the icons folder and adding the icon

```
plugins/emojione/icons/emojione.png
plugins/symbol/icons/symbol.png
```